# the type or namespace name 'webmethod' could not be found

Tags: web-services, jquery, asp.net-ajax, asmx

I'm using jquery, ajax, & .net to call a method. I see lots of examples on the net saying to put [Webmethod] above the method but I'm keeping getting the error the type or namespace name 'webmethod' could not be found. I have put "using System.Web.Services;" at the top. What else needs to be done?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

[WebMethod]
public static string GetDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Web.Services.dll` in your project.

It is most likely missing for you to be getting this error because you already have the correct `using` statement

Comment: I believe you mean just write `Using System.Web.Services;` works like a charm for me thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following on top of the page:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer to this question is to just Add reference of system.web.services from .net framework folder.

**Example:**

Consider I have a project which is already referenced **system.web.services**

[image]

Now If I right click on **System.web.services** 
[image]

You can see that this assembly is inside .Net Path so you can easily add reference of this assembly in your project from there.

[image]

**Solution**

Just right click on references ,select add reference click browser button of selection manager window go to path and add references like this.

[image]